# String starting state in C

Tags: c, string, memory, initialization

Sorry if this is a bit of a starter question but I am pretty new to C. I am using the GCC complier. When I write a program with a string in, if the string is beyond a certain length it appears to start with some contents. I am worried about just overwritting it as it could be being used by another program. Here is an example code that shows the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Using the GCC Compiler
// Why is there already something in MyString?
int main(void) {
    char MyString[250];

    printf("%s", MyString);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

How do I SAFELY avoid this issue? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's just whatever happened to be in the memory previously. It's completely fine to overwrite it, and in fact required, as you have no idea what the contents of that memory will be.

Comment: main() should return int. (your program *does* return an int value zero; although it is defined as `void main(void)` ). The program should not compile. And MyString[] is uninitialised, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is there already something in MyString?

`myString` is not initiailized and can contain anything.

To initialize to an empty string:

```
char MyString[250] = { 0 };
```

or as pointed out by [unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28169/unwind) in his answer:

```
char MyString[250] = "";
```

which is more readable (and consistent with the following).

To initialize to a string:

```
char myString[250] = "some-string";
```

> I am worried about just overwritting it as it could be being used by another program

Each running instance of your program will have its own `myString`.

Comment: If uninitialized they contain whatever was in the memory previously and it's fine to overwrite that. The thinking is that you are going to overwrite it anyway so why expend time and program code clearing it out for you...

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. Is this a safe route beacuse the piece of memory is no longer in use by the whatever other program had put something there?

Comment: @user1228123, no other program put anything there: it was just uninitialized.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your string is not initialized.

A C-String ends with ends with '\0', so you should simply put something like

```
MyString[0] = '\0';
```

behind your declaration. This way you make sure that functions like printf work the way you expect them to work.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'll try this and the { 0 } route

Answer (score 2):

For some reason many are recommending the array-style initialization of

```
char myString[50] = { 0 };
```

however, since this array is intended to be used as a string, I find it far clearer and more intuitive (and simpler syntactically) to use a string initializer:

```
char myString[50] = "";
```

This does exactly the same thing, but makes it quite a lot clearer that what you intend to initialize the array as is in fact an empty string.

The situation you're seeing with "random" data is just what happens to be in the array, since you are not initializing it you simply get what happens to be there. This does *not* mean that the memory is being used by some other program at the same time, so you don't need to worry about that. You *do* need to worry about handing a pointer to an array of `char` that is not properly 0-terminated to any C function expecting a string, though.

Technically you are then invoking *undefined behavior*, which is something you should avoid. It can easily crash your program, since there's no telling how far away into memory you might end up. Operating systems are free to kill processes that try to access memory that they're not allowed to touch.

Properly initializing the array to an empty string avoids this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
char MyString[250] = {0};
```

but for good use

```
std::string
```

Comment: `std::string` is a syntax error in C. Maybe you are confusing C and C++?

Comment: @wildplasser, the question orginally had a c++ tag which was removed.

Comment: I see.. I'll remove the comment. BTW is it valid in C++ to return 0 from a void function?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have initialzed the char array to any value, it'll contain some garbage value. It's a good programming practice to use something like:

char MyString[250] = "My Array";  // If you know the array to be used

char MyString[250] = '\0';  // If you don't intend to fill the char array data during initialization